# Netty EventExecutorGroup breaks pipeline

Tags: java, netty

**The situation:** I have a proxy app that uses Netty 4.0.17.Final (FYI: I already had the issue with versions 4.0.13.Final and 4.0.9.Final) and that's based on the [proxy from the Netty examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy).

The main difference between my code and the example is that my code doesn't connect to the backend server when the channel goes active, but only on the first read as this read must first do some checks on the input before connecting and forwarding that message to the backend server.

I have unit tested and load tested my app for hours and it works fine.

**The problem:**
As the first message received needs to perform some blocking operation I tried to use a separate `EventExecutorGroup` for that one handler that does that (so that the IO threads don't get blocked):

```
private static final EventExecutorGroup handlersExecutor = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10);
...
pipeline.addLast(handlersExecutor, "authenticationHandler", new FrontendHandler(outboundAddress));
```

This (= the only change that I made!) breaks the application during load tests. What breaks? XXX out of 3500 client connections report me that YY out of 500 messages for those clients didn't get a reply from the proxy (each request should get one response). An excerpt from the client logs:

> 2014-02-14 00:39:56.146 [id: 0x34cb2c60] ERROR (com.nsn.ucpsimulator.common.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection (/127.0.0.1:7201). PDUs received: 13
>
> 2014-02-14 00:39:56.146 [id: 0xf0955993] ERROR
>   (com.nsn.ucpsimulator.common.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection
>   (/127.0.0.1:7201). PDUs received: 13
>
> 2014-02-14 00:39:56.147 [id:
>   0x9a911fa3] ERROR
>   (com.nsn.ucpsimulator.common.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection
>   (/127.0.0.1:7201). PDUs received: 13
>
> 2014-02-14 00:39:56.149 [id:
>   0x811bbadf] ERROR
>   (com.nsn.ucpsimulator.common.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection
>   (/127.0.0.1:7201). PDUs received: 13
>
> 2014-02-14 00:39:56.150 [id:
>   0x0c4d4c5a] ERROR
>   (com.nsn.ucpsimulator.common.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection
>   (/127.0.0.1:7201). PDUs received: 13

The proxy app tells me that 500 messages were received and were forwarded, but that only 13 replies were received and forwarded back to the client:

> 2014-02-14 00:39:57.683 [id: 0x39af563b] ERROR
>   (be.demmel.fun.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection (/127.0.0.1:49359). PDUs
>   received: 500
>
> 2014-02-14 00:39:57.683 [id: 0x82056d39] ERROR
>   (be.demmel.fun.FrontendHandler) - Idle connection (/127.0.0.1:52004),
>   closing it. PDUs forwarded: 500. Success: 500
>
> 2014-02-14 00:40:00.717
>   [id: 0xcdca8f66] ERROR (be.demmel.fun.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection
>   (/127.0.0.1:7900). PDUs received: 13
>
> 2014-02-14 00:40:00.718 [id:
>   0xcdca8f66] ERROR (be.demmel.fun.BackendHandler) - Idle connection
>   (/127.0.0.1:7900). PDUs forwarded: 13. Success: 13

The server tells me that all is well:

> 2014-02-14 00:40:02.855 [id: 0x4980be2c] ERROR
>   (com.nsn.ucpsimulator.common.UcpDecoder) - Idle connection
>   (/127.0.0.1:37944). PDUs received: 500
>
> 2014-02-14 00:40:02.856 [id:
>   0x4980be2c] ERROR (com.nsn.ucpsimulator.server.TestUcpHandler) - Idle
>   connection (/127.0.0.1:37944). PDUs sent back: 500

Does somebody know what could cause this?

Additional info:

- note that everything works fine until I start using a separate `EventExecutorGroup` for the blocking handler.
- every time XX clients block, they all block at the same amount of replies forwarded to the client.
- I have uploaded the netty code here (it's runnable, contains the proxy, server and client apps with a README): https://github.com/AndrewBourgeois/ucp-proxy/tree/master/src/main/java/be/demmel/fun
- When the proxy app gets killed, this error pops up at the server side:

---

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:401) ~[netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:869) ~[netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:208) ~[netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:87) ~[netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:478) ~[netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:447) ~[netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:341) ~[netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101) [netty-all-4.0.9.Final.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

I believe that this error indicates that my Netty handlers aren't processing the server replies.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Having a peek at your github project, your execution looks a little like:

```
--> serve request
  --> authenticate (blocking db call)
    --> forward request
    <-- receive response
<-- serve response
```

Without a separate EventExecutorGroup all of your execution runs within the NioEventLoopGroup which is supposed to be used only for non-blocking actions. Each request served would decode, and then immediately block on the DB call, so your server is effectively rate-limited to the number of threads in the NioEventLoopGroup.

You have added a DefaultEventExecutorGroup around the ChannelHandler which does the authentication, so now serving requests and authenticating are partly decoupled because each request will be decoded and then execution will be passed to the DEEG, leaving the NioEventLoopGroup to decode more requests.

Except your bootstrap which connects to the DB is configured to use the same NioEventLoopGroup as the initial channel:

```
b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
```

Which means that you're still blocking your main netty worker threads with your blocking DB connection.

I'm not sure what happens after that point, but perhaps your serving a bunch of requests (effectively queueing them all up waiting on the DEEG to be available) and then timing them out because they're all waiting on the blocking DB call (which is having it's ability to execute be starved because it's in contention with server decode stuff).

i.e. (Assuming you have plenty of concurrent clients)

[original, 2 thread NioEventLoopGroup, no EventExecutorGroup]

```
nio-thread-1: serve-request 1 and authenticate (block)
nio-thread-2: serve-request 2 and authenticate (block)

(db calls completes)

nio-thread-1: forward-request 1 (non-blocking)
nio-thread-2: forward-request 2 (non-blocking)

nio-thread-1: serve-request 3 and authenticate (block)
nio-thread-2: serve-request 4 and authenticate (block)

(db calls complete)

nio-thread-1: forward-request 3 (non-blocking)
nio-thread-2: forward-request 4 (non-blocking)

nio-thread-1: either serve-response 1/2 or serve-request 5 (and block)
nio-thread-2: either serve-response 1/2 or serve-request 6 (and block)
```

It's not pretty, but you're limited to processing roughly n*2 requests at a time, assuming server-requests and server-responses are handled with the same urgency.

[2 thread NioEventLoopGroup, 2 thread DefaultEventExecutorGroup]

```
nio-thread-1: serve-request 1 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 2 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-1: serve-request 3 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 4 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-1: serve-request 5 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 6 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-1: serve-request 7 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 8 and pass to DEEG

def-evt-eg-1: try to authenticate, pass execution back to nio-thread-x
def-evt-eg-2: try to authenticate, pass execution back to nio-thread-x

nio-thread-1: serve-request 9 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 10 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-1: serve-request 11 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 12 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-1: authenticate against DB (block)
nio-thread-2: serve-request 12 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 13 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 14 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: serve-request 15 and pass to DEEG
nio-thread-2: authenticate against DB (block)
```

Now you're able to consume more requests, but the rate at which you make DB calls and total latency through your server will depend on the number of concurrent clients you have, the number of DEEG threads v number of NioEventLoop threads, context switching, etc.

You can probably visualize this by printing out some basic thread diagnostics as you run your app. I might be completely wrong as I didn't have a chance to run it and see for myself, this is just my guess.

Comment: While your point is valid (blocking Netty's IO threads IS bad), I don't think that it's the source of my issue. Authentication only happens for the first PDU after which thousands of PDUs don't block. Your second example shows why I want to use a DEEG. The EventLoop sharing thingy is something that I will look up.

Comment: Hey Andrew, did you come to a solution in the end? I'd be interested to know what the issue turned out to be.

Comment: @Norman Maurer is going to run my project to see if he can reproduce and understand the issue (check my comments on his reply). Checking the blocking issue is currently not my priority (it's not part of the code that I uploaded (and that code does reproduce my issue, ruling out your answer)).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you use create a new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(10) everything you add the handler. You should only create it one time and the pass the instance in.

Comment: Nope. I made an error when I simplified the code for this post, that's all. I just fixed that in my question. The test project on github has the correct code. Would you take the 2 mins needed to reproduce this if I gave you the client and server code (you'll only need to mvn exec:java)?

Comment: sure... just gimme the link and I will check

Comment: https://github.com/AndrewBourgeois/ucp-proxy. I added a little README.  P.S.: This code also often reproduces https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2086 (which is fixed but not released yet) ;)

Comment: I removed the "UCP" code in the github project to simplify the code even more. Let me know if you can reproduce it (I did check that I still can reproduce it without the "UCP" code). Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBourgeois I gave a try and got this from Client log "be.demmel.fun.StartClient - Number of clients that finished successfully: 4000", Can it be network stack configuration / packet loss issue in your machine?

Comment: @AndrewBourgeois I took a tcpdump while running the test, your sample program generates huge number of packets (3745442) in short time. I saw lot of tcp packet loss / retransmissions going time to time (tcp.analysis.* filter in wireshark). Can it be like "after adding the separate executor, the remote was writing too fast and few clients might have lost the packets ?

Comment: @JestanNirojan The problem does indeed only occur under heavy load (as stated in my question), so the client does indeed create 4000 connections (which you can increase between tests if it runs fine with 4k clients) to send 500 PDUs per connection. I really don't know where to start looking (o prove that component X of the networking stack is at fault), but I do know that tcpdump's output is unreliable under heavy load. Note that I removed the blocking part for the example app, so it shouldn't be faster with a separate executor.

Comment: @JestanNirojan Also note that the client app only counts the clients that received 500 replies from the proxy. So if it logs that 4k clients finished successfully, it means the problem didn't occur (with 4k clients the issue arises every 2 executions for me). You might want to add 1k clients to see if it's still OK.